# GCP anonymous calls to API

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform

I´m startig with GCP now and I have started a new vm in the compute instance in the cloud. When I go to the API & Services and then the metrics in the compute engine, although I have created an OAuth2 and API key to avoid others to call my project using this API, I don´t know how to block anonymous calls and if they are legitimate.

Is there a way to stop all calls but the just strictly required?
[GCP API metrics view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh8ad.png)

Answer (score 1):

In front of your VM you can plug (Identity Aware Proxy (IAP)](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs) to allow access only to people authenticated.

If you want to manage your authentication with API Keys, you can plug Cloud Endpoint in front of your IAP for translating the API Keys validation to IAP Call. [I wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1). In this article, the AppEngine case is the same because AppEngine can be also protected by IAP.